# Highcharts - How do I track/follow a live updated chart without using a navigator?

Tags: javascript, charts, highcharts, angular2-highcharts

I have a graph which has live data feeding in, but the chart only tracks or follows the data line if the navigator is enabled.

I am unsure if this is a feature or is it a bug.

On the JSFiddle, notice how it doesn't track, but as soon as you change `enabled: false` to `enabled: true`, on `line 43`, it instantly starts tracking.

http://jsfiddle.net/6eso1hgy/1/

Is it possible to make it have the tracking behavior without a navigator?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you really need Highstock. If not then you can change the code to just Highcharts and then remove all unnecessary code and add the following:

```
series: [{
  marker: {
    radius: 0
  },
...
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/core972/8Lea9gyv/)

Comment: Yup, I require highstock, working on a financial tool

Comment: @Dolan, Then navigator is required.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve it using `xAxis.setExtremes()` method:

**Code:**

```
events: {
  load: function() {
    // set up the updating of the chart each second
    var series = this.series[0];
    var chart = this;
    setInterval(function() {
      NewTime = (new Date()).getTime(); // current time
      var x = NewTime,
        y = Math.round(Math.random() * 10);

      series.addPoint([x, y], false, false, false); //redraw shift animation

      chart.xAxis[0].setExtremes(
        chart.xAxis[0].min + 1000,
        chart.xAxis[0].max + 1000,
        true,
        false
      );
    }, 1000);
  }
}
```

**Demo:**

- http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/z1mu0Lgh/

**API reference:**

- https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.Axis#setExtremes

Comment: This is a little bit of a hack with `setInterval` so I am not too happy with this answer. Ideally I wan't it to just work without any faffing about, but I will try it!